# STIG (Security Technical Implementation Guides) automation

Tags: rhel, security, configuration

Has anyone here found the best way to STIG a version of RHEL 6.x automatically? The other answers I have found are either out of date or do not completely STIG the machine. Even an image that has a STIG of RHEL will help.

Comment: What's a STIG in this context?

Comment: @Gilles - The Security Technical Implementation Guides (STIGs) and the NSA Guides are the configuration standards for DOD IA and IA-enabled devices/systems. http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/index.html

Comment: Related discussion: [Difference between hardening guides (CIS, NSA, DISA)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73164/difference-between-hardening-guides-cis-nsa-disa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This project sounds like what you're looking for, titled: [stig-fix-el6](https://github.com/RedHatGov/stig-fix-el6).

*excerpt*

> DISA STIG Scripts to harden a system to the RHEL 6 STIG.
>
> These scripts will harden a system to specifications that are based
>   upon the the following previous hardening  provided by the following
>   projects:
>
> DISA RHEL 6 STIG V1 R2
>
> - http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/os/unix/red_hat.html
>
> NIST 800-53 (USGCB) Content for RHEL 5
>
> - http://usgcb.nist.gov/usgcb/rhel_content.html
>
> NSA SNAC Guide for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5
>
> - http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/os/redhat/NSA_RHEL_5_GUIDE_v4.2.pdf
>
> Aqueduct Project
>
> - https://fedorahosted.org/aqueduct
>
> Tresys Certifiable Linux Integration Platform (CLIP)
>
> - http://oss.tresys.com/projects/clip

The contents of the project includes the following scripts:

```
apply.sh - master script that runs scripts in cat1-cat4 and misc
toggle_ipv6.sh - toggles IPv6 support, requires reboot (default is off)
toggle_nousb.sh - toggles the 'nousb' kernel flag only
toggle_udf.sh - toggles 'udf' mounting of DVDs (USGCB Blacklists udf) 
toggle_usb.sh - toggles 'nousb' kernel flag and the mass storage kernel 
                module config - Directory with some pre-STIGed 
                configurations (auditd,iptables,system-auth-local,etc.) 
cat1 - CAT I STIG Scripts
cat2 - CAT II STIG Scripts
cat3 - CAT III STIG Scripts
cat4 - CAT IV STIG Scripts
misc - NSA SNAC, GNOME, and Other miscellenous lockdown scripts
manual - Manaully run (There be dragons here)
backups - Backup copy of modified files to compare and restore configurations
```

Comment: I used something similar a long time ago for RHEL 5, assuming this one works as well.

Comment: Yes it does, it was the most I was able to STIG the machine without having to spend hours in front of the machine just setting it up.

Comment: **Review each script before you run it, AND test it in non-production environment before using it in production.**